# Macro is not picking up hyphens within text

Tags: vba, ms-word

Having a bit of an error with a macro that was working earlier today. We have a macro that searches a word document for certain words, and changes the font type when it detects them. For some reason, we added a new word/phrase, that contains a hyphen, for example this-word. There is no space either side of the hyphen, and I can't work out why it wont detect. Below is an example of the code.

```
       With Selection.Find
        .Text = "hyphenated-word"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Whitney Bold"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWholeWord = True
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

For all intents and purposes, the code itself works with other words, such as "your" etc, but with this it doesn't. Is there a rule im missing?

Comment: If you test in Word's UI (Ctrl+H) do you get the same result? Are you sure the hyphen is truly a hyphen and not a non-breaking hyphen or an optional hyphen? (One will always force both sides of the hyphen to stay together on a line, not break at the end of a line; the other will only display if hyphenation is active and the word breaks at the end of a line.) If you copy the term then paste it into the Find dialog's "Find what" box, does Find/Replace then work?

Comment: Are you sure the word is in your `Selection` when you run this macro?

Comment: Testing with your code I found no issues replacing words that contained hyphens. I did however have issues replacing a word with a "" blank string. It ignored the replace in those cases but did properly format the word based on the Font format change. Change the .Replacement.Text = "" to = " " to see if you can replace with a single space.  I think there is something flaky going on with this function.